# How to get Svelte to react to changes in a variable

Tags: svelte

I am attempting to get my Svelte App to react to changes to a dictionary defined in a data-store

In the following code [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b23e2b59cb24441da67b66f58ac11301?version=3.55.0), the *createNewItem* function gets called when a new item is created and the *user* store gets updated between the *ante* and *post* displays in that function, but the *getOptions* function does not get called even though *user.options* is demonstrably changed. What is the problem?

**App.svelete**

```
<select bind:value={selectedOption}>
{#each user_options as option}
    <option value={option}>{option}</option>
{/each}
</select>

<button on:click={addNewItem}>New item</button>
<NewItem />

<script>
    import {user, state, elementDisplay } from './data'
import NewItem from "./NewItem.svelte";
    
$: user_options = getOptions($user.options);
$: new_item = createNewItem($state.new_item);
    
let selectedOption = "";
    
    function getOptions(user_options) {
        console.log('user changed')
        let options = []
        if (state.new_item != '') {
            user_options[$user.new_item] = ''
        }
        for (const [option, value] of Object.entries(user_options)) {
            options.push(option)
        }
        return options
    }
    
    function createNewItem(new_item) {
            if (new_item.length > 0 ) {
                console.log('ante', $user)
                $user.options[new_item] = '';
                console.log('post', $user)
            }
        }

function addNewItem() {
        elementDisplay('new-item', 'block')
        document.getElementById('new-item-value').focus();
    }
</script>
```

**NewItem.svelte**

```
<div id="new-item">
    <input type="text" id="new-item-value">
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="select-button" on:click={useItem}>Use</button>
        <button class="select-button" on:click={close}>Close</button>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #new-item {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    import { state, elementDisplay } from './data'

    function useItem() {
        let input_field = document.getElementById('new-item-value')
        if (input_field.value) {
            $state.new_item = input_field.value
        }
        close()
    }

    function close() {
            elementDisplay('new-item', 'none');
        }
</script>
```

**data.js**

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export let user = writable({
    new_item: '',
    options: {
    "2": "Option 2",
    "1": "Option 1",
    "3": "Option 3",
        }
    }
);

export let state = writable({
    new_item: '',
});

export function elementDisplay(item_name, display) {
    let item = document.getElementById(item_name);
    item.style.display = display;
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: swap the order of those two `$:` reactive statements, and you'll get desired result.

### Explanation

Normally order of $-statements doesn't matter. However in your case there's a hidden causality between `createNewItem` function and `$user` variable, which svelte compiler fails to notice.

What happened? It all boils down to how svelte compiles the reactive statements.

```
$: user_options = getOptions($user.options);
$: new_item = createNewItem($state.new_item);

/** ABOVE IS COMPILED INTO BELOW */

$$self.$$.update = () => {
    if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*$user*/ 8) {
        $$invalidate(0, user_options = getOptions($user.options));
    }

    if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*$state*/ 16) {
        $: new_item = createNewItem($state.new_item);
    }
};
```

Notice that all reactive statements are packed into one single `$$.update` function.

Your chain of reaction goes like this:

```
1) NewItem.svelte#useItem() -> $state.new_item = "..." -> 
2) $: new_item = createNewItem($state.new_item) -> $user.options[new_item] = '' -> 
3) $: user_options = getOptions($user.options);
```

Hidden causality (or "dependency" if you like) lies inside `createNewItem($state.new_item)` (second $-statement) where `$user.options` is mutated. It then in turn causes `getOptions($user.options)` (first $-statement) to run.

That's your intention. However the way svelte interprets things goes like this:

- The compiler packs both $-statements into the same `$$.update` function, which will just execute JUST ONCE during each update cycle ([source](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/670f4580568fe8ea31097981ba2d59c33daf0725/src/runtime/internal/scheduler.ts#L99-L109)).
- `useItem() -> $state.new_item` triggers a new update cycle, so `$$.update()` is called to run those `$:` reactions.
- `if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*$user*/ 8)` check runs first, it sees `$user` is not dirty *AT THIS POINT*, so it moves on.
- `if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*$state*/ 16)` sees that `$state` is dirty, so it runs `createNewItem($state.new_item)`
- If we were to run the `if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*$user*/ 8)` check again, we'd see `$user` dirty by now! But it's too late, because the way svelte compiles, we've moved pass that point already.

### Solution

The quick fix, you just need to swap the order of $-statements:

```
$: new_item = createNewItem($state.new_item);
$: user_options = getOptions($user.options);
```

In fact the [svelte docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive) has a very similar example that talks about this caveat:

> It is important to note that the reactive blocks are ordered via simple static analysis at compile time, and all the compiler looks at are the variables that are assigned to and used within the block itself, not in any functions called by them. This means that yDependent will not be updated when x is updated in the following example: [...]

> Moving the line $: yDependent = y below $: setY(x) will cause yDependent to be updated when x is updated.

However I'd personally avoid this kind of deeply (and hidden) chained reactivity altogether. To me this is a huge red-flagged anti-pattern. The dependency is hidden to begin with, the reaction chain is convoluted, and plus this ordering caveat which is hard to notice, why would you get yourself into this mess?

Better organize your code into more clear structure, instead of jump wiring bad designs.

Comment: Well, I got myself into this "mess" because this is a highly simplified, but reproducible, example of the problem. The original is an attempt to abstract the process of adding a new item to multiple data structures. your explanation is excellent and much appreciated